# Need reference for this hadith

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I need reference for the following hadith to verify its validity :

> "Once Moosa (AS) asked Allah Subhaana'O'Ta'ala:
>
> O Allah! You have granted me the honor and privilege of talking to you
>   directly, Have you given this privilege to any other person?
>
> Allah Ta'ala replied, O!! Moosa during the last period I am going to
>   send an Ummat, who will be the Ummat of Mohammed (SAW) with dry lips,
>   parched tongues, emaciated body with eyes sunken deep into their
>   sockets, with livers dry and stomachs suffering the pangs of hunger
>   will call out to me (in dua) they will be much much closer to me than
>   you O Moosa! while you speak to me there are 70000 veils between you
>   and me but at the time of iftaar there will not be a single veil
>   between me and the fasting Ummati of Mohammed (SAW) O!! Moosa I have
>   taken upon myself the responsibility that at the time of iftaar I will
>   never refuse the dua of a fasting person!"

May Allah bless u all.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned by Abdul Rahman bin Abdul Salam as-Safuri in his book *Nuzhat al-Majalis wa Muntakhab al-Nafais* and it's a fabricated tradition that has no authenticity to it nor any reporters going back to the Prophet.

This is the Arabic:

قال موسى عليه السلام : يا رب ! أكرمتني بالتكليم ، فهل أعطيت أحداً مثل ذلك ؟ فأوحى الله تعالى : يا موسى ! إن لي عباداً أخرجهم في آخر الزمان وأكرمهم بشهر رمضان فأكون أقرب لأحدهم منك ؛ لأنك كلمتني وبيني وبينك سبعون ألف حجاب ، فإذا صامت أمة محمد صلى الله عليه وسلم حتى ابيضت شفاههم ، واصفرت ألوانهم، أرفع الحجب بيني وبينهم وقت إفطارهم . يا موسى ! طوبى لمن عطش كبده ، وأجاع بطنه في رمضان